# How to use LifecycleScope to execute coroutine

Tags: kotlin

I am discovering Kotlin and android app dev. I fail to get data from my `room` database (because of `Cannot access database on the main thread`). So I try with [lifecyclescope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope).

The concerned code, in Fragment `onViewCreated` function, is :

```kotlin
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                val accountConfiguration = viewModel.get();
                println("{${accountConfiguration}}")
            }
        }
```

The called function (in viewModel) is :

```kotlin
    fun get() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.get()
    }
```

There is the "full" code (simplified), Entity & DAO :

```kotlin
@Entity
data class AccountConfiguration(
    @PrimaryKey val server_address: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_name") val user_name: String,
    // [...]
)

@Dao
interface AccountConfigurationDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM accountconfiguration LIMIT 1")
    fun flow(): Flow<AccountConfiguration?>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM accountconfiguration LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun get(): AccountConfiguration?
    // [...]
}
```

Repository :

```kotlin
package fr.bux.rollingdashboard

import androidx.annotation.WorkerThread
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

class AccountConfigurationRepository(private val accountConfigurationDao: AccountConfigurationDao) {
    val accountConfiguration: Flow<AccountConfiguration?> = accountConfigurationDao.flow()

    // [...]

    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun get() : AccountConfiguration? {
        return accountConfigurationDao.get()
    }
}
```

ViewModel & Factory :

```kotlin
class AccountConfigurationViewModel(private val repository: AccountConfigurationRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val accountConfiguration: LiveData<AccountConfiguration?> = repository.accountConfiguration.asLiveData()

    // [...]
    fun get() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.get()
    }
    // [...]
}

class AccountConfigurationViewModelFactory(private val repository: AccountConfigurationRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(AccountConfigurationViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return AccountConfigurationViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

Fragment :

```kotlin
class AccountConfigurationFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: AccountConfigurationFragmentBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val viewModel: AccountConfigurationViewModel by activityViewModels {
        AccountConfigurationViewModelFactory(
            (activity?.application as RollingDashboardApplication).account_configuration_repository
        )
    }
    lateinit var accountConfiguration: AccountConfiguration

    // [...]

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.buttonGoBackMain.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_AccountConfigurationFragment_to_DashboardFragment)
        }

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                val accountConfiguration = viewModel.get();
                println("{${accountConfiguration}}")
            }
        }

        binding.buttonSave.setOnClickListener {
            save()
        }

    }

    // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code,

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val accountConfiguration = viewModel.get();
        println("{${accountConfiguration}}")
    }
}
```

- `viewModel.get()` is not a suspend function, so it returns immediately and proceeds to the next line. It actually returns the `Job` created by `viewModelScope.launch()`.
- If you want your coroutine to wait for the result before continuing you should make the `get()` function suspend and return the `AccountConfiguration?`

  ```kotlin
  suspend fun get(): AccountConfiguration? {
      return repository.get()
  }
  ```
- You need not change dispatchers to `Dispatchers.Default` because Room itself will switch to a background thread before executing any database operation.
- Right now if there is a configuration change while coroutines inside `lifecyclerScope` are running, everything will get cancelled and restarted.
  A better way would have been to put the suspending calls inside the ViewModel and expose a LiveData/Flow to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the viewModel function :

```kotlin
    fun get() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.get()
    }
```

This function must be the coroutine instead launch the coroutine itself. Correct code is :

```kotlin
    suspend fun get(): AccountConfiguration? {
        return repository.get()
    }
```